# Bokeh line on/off example is not working as it should

Tags: python, bokeh

I am playing around with Bokeh CustomJS filters and am interested in toggling plot elements on and off, and I am using [the line_on_off.py example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-2.3/examples/plotting/file/line_on_off.py) without making any changes to the code. When I plot this in Jupyter notebook I run into an issue: no matter which checkbox I turn off first, the last line (the yellow tangent plot) always toggles off first. For example, if I turn off the "Line 0" button first, the last line disappears, same with turning off either the "Line 1" and "Line 2" buttons first. Furthermore, turning off any second checkbox always toggles off the "Line 1" plot (the second plot).

It looks like the code is always toggling off the last visible rendered plot, no matter which checkbox button is actually clicked. I have been doing a lot of reading on Bokeh's CustomJS and have come across multiple questions here from users who have used this same example, seemingly without the issue I'm having. Is there a bug in the example or am I not utilizing the js code correctly?

I am using:

- python 3.7.6
- bokeh 2.3.3
- jupyter 1.0.0.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experiment on my jupyter notebook I was able to reproduce the behaviour you discribed. With some small changes in the JavaScript part the example works perfect.

I changed `0 in checkbox.active` to `checkbox.active.includes(0)` and the same for 1 and 2. My guess is that the first one is looking for the index and not the value but I am not a expert in JavaScript.

Here is the complete working example.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
l0 = p.line(x, np.sin(x), color=Viridis3[0], legend_label="Line 0", **props)
l1 = p.line(x, 4 * np.cos(x), color=Viridis3[1], legend_label="Line 1", **props)
l2 = p.line(x, np.tan(x), color=Viridis3[2], legend_label="Line 2", **props)

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"],
                         active=[0, 1, 2], width=100)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2, checkbox=checkbox), code="""
console.log(checkbox.active)

l0.visible = checkbox.active.includes(0);
l1.visible = checkbox.active.includes(1);
l2.visible = checkbox.active.includes(2);
""")

checkbox.js_on_change('active', callback)

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I'm even less of a Javascript expert than you and figured I could probably change something up there.